# How to implement logout with custom authentication routes in ServiceStack

Tags: c#, authentication, servicestack

Simple question, I've got the code below to specify the routes for my user authentication using a custom CredentialsAuthProvider (put together using what I found in the documentation)

```
// inside 'Configure()'....
Dictionary<Type, string[]> serviceRoutes = new Dictionary<Type, string[]>();
serviceRoutes.Add(typeof(AuthService), new[] { "/user/auth" });           
AuthFeature authFeature = new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(), new IAuthProvider[] {
    new myCompany.web.JSONService.myCompanyCredentialsAuthProvider() 
});
authFeature.IncludeAssignRoleServices = false;
authFeature.ServiceRoutes = serviceRoutes; //specify manual auth routes            
Plugins.Add(authFeature);
```

which creates a route of /user/auth, what I'd also like is a route like this :

```
/user/logout
```

but there is very little in the documentation about logout functionality. Is this a custom route I have to build into my service like all my other API calls, or is there a configuration option I can use?

Also, i'm currently using the swagger plugin to document and test my service, but it shows me the `/user/auth` route as 'get' enabled, I'd like to restrict it to 'post' verb only, if that's possible? Secondary question, mostly want to know correct way to implement logout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AuthFeature` creates a route at `/auth/logout` and you can hit it with a GET or POST to log out

Comment: the Swagger plugin doesn't expose the logout route, would be good if it did, and i'd prefer it too be configurable as well, oh well. This worked thanks.

Comment: Probably because the route is actually "/auth/{provider}" where "logout" is a special provider value.